# mail command : does content-filter in postfix works?

Tags: email, postfix, command-line-interface, content-filter

I use Postfix in my machine (linux).

When i send a mail to a local user with **telnet localhost 25** in command line, my mail is parsed by a content-filter (for example: spamassassin) => no problem.

But when i send a mail to the same local user with **mail command** (or sendmail command or mail php), my mail is sent but not parsed by the content-filter => so why ?

Why my mail is not parsed by a content-filter when i use the mail command ?

My postfix configuration is very basic :

postconf -n :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost.localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
```

postconf -M :

```
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
pickup     fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
spamassassin unix -      n       n       -       -       pipe user=mail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${user} -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I repeat my problem : when i use telnet localhost 25 to send a mail to a local user (guest), spamassassin parse the mail, and syslog displays :

```
Feb  4 15:05:42 localhost postfix/smtpd[3919]: connect from localhost[::1]
Feb  4 15:05:50 localhost postfix/smtpd[3919]: EBC2460DBF: client=localhost[::1]
Feb  4 15:05:59 localhost postfix/cleanup[3922]: EBC2460DBF: message-id=<20150204140550.EBC2460DBF@localhost>
Feb  4 15:05:59 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: EBC2460DBF: from=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, size=342, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  4 15:05:59 localhost spamd[18634]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 48540
Feb  4 15:05:59 localhost spamd[18634]: spamd: processing message <20150204140550.EBC2460DBF@localhost> for guest:122
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost spamd[18634]: spamd: clean message (0.2/5.0) for guest:122 in 9.1 seconds, 296 bytes.
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost spamd[18634]: spamd: result: . 0 - ALL_TRUSTED,MISSING_HEADERS scantime=9.1,size=296,user=guest,uid=122,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=48540,mid=<20150204140550.EBC2460DBF@localhost>,autolearn=ham
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost spamd[18632]: prefork: child states: II
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/pickup[3881]: 6844560FDB: uid=8 from=<guest@localhost.localdomain>
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/pipe[3923]: EBC2460DBF: to=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<guest>, relay=spamassassin, delay=22, delays=12/0.01/0/9.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: EBC2460DBF: removed
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/cleanup[3922]: 6844560FDB: message-id=<20150204140550.EBC2460DBF@localhost>
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: 6844560FDB: from=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, size=656, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/local[3928]: 6844560FDB: to=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.18, delays=0.12/0.01/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb  4 15:06:08 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: 6844560FDB: removed
```

=> no problem.

But if i use just the mail command :

```
echo "test" | mail -s "test" guest
```

, the mail is sent, but spamassassin has not parsed the mail because syslog displays this :

```
Feb  4 15:09:36 localhost postfix/pickup[3881]: B6C1960DC0: uid=1000 from=<guest>
Feb  4 15:09:36 localhost postfix/cleanup[3956]: B6C1960DC0: message-id=<20150204140936.B6C1960DC0@localhost>
Feb  4 15:09:36 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: B6C1960DC0: from=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, size=339, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  4 15:09:36 localhost postfix/local[3957]: B6C1960DC0: to=<guest@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<guest>, relay=local, delay=0.18, delays=0.12/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Feb  4 15:09:36 localhost postfix/qmgr[3883]: B6C1960DC0: removed
```

An idea ?

Thanks, cordially.

Comment: What is type of your content filter? The [simple one](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter) or the [advanced one](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#advanced_filter)? If you are unsure, you can edit the question and post the output of `postconf -n` and `postconf -M`

Comment: Hi masegaloeh, thanks for your reply, i have just edit my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For content filter after queue, postfix has two implementation methods, the simple and advanced content filter. You can read the explanation of both methods [in its official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

From your question, we can learn that you use simple content filter method. The sign is output of `postconf -M` (or the content of `master.cf`). It uses pipe method to pass email to spam assassin via command

```
/usr/bin/spamc -u ${user} -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

[Postfix official docs above](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter) also tell you the major limitation of simple content filter

> The first example is simple to set up, but has major limitations that will be addressed in a second example. Postfix receives unfiltered mail from the network with the smtpd(8) server, and delivers unfiltered mail to a content filter with the Postfix pipe(8) delivery agent. The content filter injects filtered mail back into Postfix with the Postfix sendmail(1) command, so that Postfix can deliver it to the final destination.
>
> **This means that mail submitted via the Postfix sendmail(1) command cannot be content filtered.**

So, the behavior that you see was normal.

#### Solution: How can I use content_filter for email submitted via mail command?

You can consider to switch your setup to use advanced content filter method. [This thread on spam assassin mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/spamassassin/mailman/message/15523324/) tell you some alternative to achieve this: [amavisd](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/) or [spampd](http://www.worlddesign.com/index.cfm/rd/mta/spampd.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so i should try the advanced method for content-filter

Comment: Yep, you should. Anyway if this answer was solved your problem, you can consider to [accept it](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) so this question doesn't float in unanswered  pool.

Comment: It's solved, thanks to you. I integrated spamassassin in postfix with the same method than amavisd. Thank you very much. But i have a another question : I want to modify the mail address in return-path field with this mail command : echo "test" | mail -a "Return-Path: other@example.com" -s "test" guest .But it doesn't work, in the source code of the received mail, the email address in Return-Path: field is always the same of the email address in From: field, it is normal ?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it in new question by click **Ask Question** button